# Erro em um método exportado de um módulo com Typescript

Tags: typescript

Estou tentando exportar uma classe específica de um módulo, até aqui está tudo certo. Eu declarei a minha classe como **abstract** para não precisar inicializa-lá com o **new**, porém ao tentar utilizar a função **"getItem()"** o compilador me retorna o seguinte error:

> TS2339: Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'typeof WebStorage'

**MÓDULO:**

```
interface IStorage {
    setItem(key : string, value: any) : void;
    getItem(key : string) : any;
    getItem(key : string) : any;
}

export abstract class WebLocalStorage implements IStorage {
    public setItem(key : string, value : any) { 
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    public getItem(key : string) : any { 
        localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
}

export abstract class WebStorage implements IStorage {
    public setItem(key : string, value : any) { 
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    public getItem(key : string) : any { 
        sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }

}
```

**LOCAL ONDE ESTÁ SENDO IMPORTADO O MÓDULO:**

```
import { WebStorage } from '../../HTMLAPIS/WebStorageAPI';

export default class FilterData {
    private readonly _typingValue: HTMLInputElement;
    private readonly _containerMain: HTMLElement;
    private readonly _listboxMain: HTMLElement;
    private readonly _listboxSecondary: HTMLElement;

    constructor(public typingValue: HTMLInputElement, public containerMain : HTMLElement, public listboxMain : HTMLElement,  public listboxSecondary : HTMLElement) {
        this._typingValue      = typingValue;
        this._containerMain    = containerMain;
        this._listboxMain      = listboxMain;
        this._listboxSecondary = listboxSecondary;
    }

    public initComponent() {
        this.keypress();
    }

    private keypress() {
        this._typingValue.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
            console.log(WebStorage.getItem('shopkeepers_names'));
        });
    }

    searchData() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mas `abstract` não significa que você não precisa utilizar `new`, abstract significa que essa classe não pode ser utilizada diretamente e deve ser implementada por outra classe.

Para utilizar um método sem criar um objeto, o que você precisa é de `static`.

```
class WebStorage implements IStorage {
    public static setItem(key : string, value : any) { 
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    public static getItem(key : string) : string { 
        return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }
}
```

Em nota: `sessionStorage` só armazena strings. Você pode até passar um numérico, mas esse numérico será convertido antes de ser armazenado.

Comment: O problema disto é que o compilador vai reclamar por conta da INTERFACE!

Comment: Ah sim. Mas se sua interface diz que os métodos não podem ser estáticos, então não tem como você utiliza-los sem criar um objeto. Você pode mudar a declaração dos métodos na interface, ou criar métodos diferentes nas classes que a implementa. Se você pudesse contradizer a regra que você criou, de que serviria a regra?